# Problems releted to the Media Player

Tags: android, media-player

Hi I am facing a problem related to the Media Player. I've created an object of `MediaPlayer` and played it inside `onCreate()` method. It was working fine at the staring but now it is creating a problem.

My problem is that sound is playing in background with little bit delay. So its like a repeating a sound in background.

Please suggest me something.

Comment: Does it happen on changing the orientation of your device?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is playing in background with delay... but it must be starting the sound again and again as you change the orientation of your device... if that is the problem try this..
    add this to your activity in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

and put this in your activity class

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: is it happening when you are changing the orientation? or every time right from launching your app?